# SpriteKit Memory increase every time new scene presented

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to solve an issue where SpriteKit is causing memory leakage every time I re-open a scene after dismissing it and it's view controller. This is the upwards trend every time it's opened:
[image: spritekit memory leak]

When I check instruments, the issue appears to be with the SKTileMapNode "SKCTileMapNode::_ensureChunkForTileIndex(unsigned int)" but I am using this code upon willMove(from view: SKView):

```
 for child in children {
        if child.isKind(of: SKTileMapNode.self) {
            (child as! SKTileMapNode).fill(with: nil)
            print("Wiped tiles for tilemaps")
            child.removeAllActions()
            child.removeFromParent()
        } else if child.isKind(of: SKSpriteNode.self) {
            (child as! SKSpriteNode).texture = nil
            child.removeAllActions()
            child.removeFromParent()
            print("Wiped SKSpriteKitNodes")
        } else {
            print("Other child removed")
            child.removeAllActions()
            child.removeFromParent()
        }

    }
```

And as you can see from the image above, the result is still upwards of memory usage. Still with the SKTileMapNode in instruments?

Comment: Are you saying that you only have SKTileMapNode objects in your game?

Comment: No I’m saying they are what appears to be leaking memory when I check in instruments. Even though I’m emptying them and clearing them out.

Comment: There's probably an object that is still referencing the nodes you are removing. If you subclassed SKTileMapNode put  in deinit { print("TileNode Deinitialized") } . If no print occurs when you remove the node in your code above, then that's the problem.

Comment: I agree with @Muffinman2497, log the SKScene deinit, if it's not called, you could log the deinit for every class you're using and check which one doesn't call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried checking if things had not been deallocated and this did not solve the problem. I used a developer technical support ticket and an engineer advised me to turn off "GPU Frame Capture" in the scheme for the project.

This 95% solved the problem. Memory usage has reduced to a lot more reasonable amount and the app no longer continues to build up memory usage after I implement reasonable methods to deallocate scenes, nodes etc...

I asked if this solution was only for testing in Xcode and I was told it was not, this is how my app will perform on the App Store:

"GPU Frame Capture is a tool for debugging and is only present when running your app with the Xcode Debugger attached!" - Said the engineer.